What do you do with SDL2 events?
I have the typical/basic event loop for SDL2 and I'm a little confused on what to do with them or how to handle them or I guess more specifically how should I get the data from these events (e.g SDL_QUIT, SDL_WINDOWEVENT, SDL_KEYDOWN) to other areas of code.
In past projects I tried dabbling with my own event system so I took the data from the SDL event and converted it into my own application event like this:
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    switch (event.type) {
    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        events.fire<KeyEvent>(true, event.key.keysym.sym);
        break;
    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        events.fire<KeyEvent>(true, event.key.keysym.sym);
        break;
    }

I have a feeling that this probably isn't a bad solution and I'm just overthinking, but this feels a bit bizarre because SDL already provides you with the event and its data and I'm trying to stuff it into my own probably worst event system although perhaps I'm just not realizing the benefit of something like this.
The other idea I came to was just calling a function that stores/saves the data to be accessed later like this:
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    switch (event.type) {
    case SDL_QUIT:
        gameDetails.requestExit(); // Would set some bool to true which the main loop would check via gameDetails.shouldExit()
        break;
    }

Curious if either of this examples would be a "typical" approach or if there is a better way to go about this. My end goal is basically being able to send this data around for example for a SDL_WINOWEVENTmy renderer might be interested so that it can resize things.

For events that may not be processed immediately, like your example quit event, you can use an Event Queue as an alternative to setting boolean flags. It's probably overkill if you're only using one or two flags, but if you've got a large number of delayed events, or need to do advanced things like process them in a particular order or potentially modify or cancel them, then an Event Queue can be very helpful.
